# Cypress intercept registering too late after button click

Tags: frontend, cypress, e2e-testing, cy.intercept

And thank you in advance!

I am working on some cypress E2E tests, and having some issues with the intercept. I have a button that upon click, shall send a PUT request to the backend to change the status of a user, for which I have written the test as follows:

```js
it('should test that the PUT request is called upon button click', () => {
    cy.intercept({
        method: 'PUT', 
        url: `/someUrl`,
        query: {
             status: 'Online'
        },
    }).as('changeUserStatus')
    
    cy.get(`button`).click()
    cy.wait('@changeUserStatus').its('response.statusCode').should('eq', 200);
})
```

However, when the button is clicked, the PUT XHR call appears before the wait @changeAgentStatus, which results in the test failing.

I also saw this article: https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-intercept-problems/#the-intercept-was-registered-too-late
and from reading the article have tried to put the `cy.intercept` block of code in a `before(() => {})` block, but am still facing the same problem.

Any help on this is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

If the button is triggering the PUT then the intercept isn't too late.

More likely the matcher is incorrect.

Try with a wildcard that catches anything

```js
cy.intercept({
  method: 'PUT', 
  url: `*`,
  times: 1,           // just the next request
}).as('changeUserStatus')
```

If that works, you have verified the intercept is in the right place in the test.

Other matcher to try

```js
cy.intercept({
  method: 'PUT', 
  pathname: `/someurl`,    // From docs: Like path, but without query parameters
  query: {
    status: 'Online'
  },
}).as('changeUserStatus')
```

Ref [RouteMatcher](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#routeMatcher-RouteMatcher)

> **url**   Full HTTP request URL
> **path**  HTTP request path after the hostname, including query parameters
> **pathname**  Like path, but without query parameters