# Cypress wait starts after intercept finishes

Tags: cypress, cypress-intercept

I have a similar problem to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71583919/cypress-intercept-registering-too-late-after-button-click) that my `cy.wait()` only starts waiting after all the `cy.intercept()` stub the API responses:

```
  beforeEach(function () {
    cy.intercept('GET', '**/api/**',
      (req) => {
        req.reply({
          body: my_response,
        });
      }).as('login_api_1');
    // and a few more intercepts like the above 
    cy.login(); // this login here will click on the login button which triggers all the API calls
    cy.wait(['@login_api_1', '@login_api_2', ...]) // it looks like when I wait for just one of the APIs, it works fine. But if I try to wait for all of them, the wait is too slow and the responses get stubbed first already
  });
```

With the above code snippet, my API calls are all stubbed with `my_response` already **before** the wait starts, so `cy.wait()` just times out.

This is my test:

```
    it('tests something', () => {
       //cy.wait(1000)
       cy.intercept('GET', '**/api/**').as('api');
       // click buttons to trigger the API call again
       cy.wait('@api');
```

If I use the `cy.wait(1000)` here inside the test and remove the `cy.wait('@login_*)`, the code will work just fine. So it just looks like the `cy.wait('@login_*)` is not fast enough after the login. I tried putting the wait function inside of the login function right after the button click for logging in but still the same issue. So my question is that either:

1. Is there a way to make `cy.wait()` "fast" enough so it waits for the api calls intercepted?
2. Or, if I do not use `cy.wait()` at all. But in my test, my second intercept (in the test) can wait until the first intercept (in `beforeEach`) finishes. Because without any `cy.wait()`, the intercept in my test will try to intercept the API call from the login instead of the button clicks

UPDATE:

Or maybe a better question could be, how do I wait for the first `cy.intercept` to stub the response (inside the `beforeEach`) finishes, before I can stub the response again of the second API call (inside the test)?

CURRENT WORKAROUND:

I modified this line:

```
cy.wait(['@login_api_1', '@login_api_2', ...])
```

to be:

```
cy.wait(@login_api_1')
cy.wait(@login_api_2')
// and a few more waits on the rest of the api calls
```

Somehow this seems to work fine for now.

Answer (score 2):

#### Short answer

Setting up an identical intercept will not catch multiple calls - the last one created will catch all the calls.

Instead, use a single intercept and wait on it multiple times.

---

#### Examples

**Failing with multiple intercepts**

```js
const my_response = {}   // anything will do here

cy.intercept('GET', '**/api/**',
  (req) => {
    req.reply({
      body: my_response,
    });
  }).as('login_api_1')

cy.intercept('GET', '**/api/**',
  (req) => {
    req.reply({
      body: my_response,
    });
  }).as('login_api_2')

// trigger a couple of requests to that URL
cy.window().then(win => {
  win.fetch('domain/api/1')
  win.fetch('domain/api/2')
})

cy.wait(['@login_api_1', '@login_api_2'])
```

The result is a timeout on `@login_api_1` because `@login_api_2` has blocked the first intercept.

[image]

---

**Passing with multiple waits**

```js
const my_response = {}   

cy.intercept('GET', '**/api/**',
  (req) => {
    req.reply({
      body: my_response,
    });
  }).as('login_api')

cy.window().then(win => {
  win.fetch('domain/api/1')
  win.fetch('domain/api/2')
})

// wait for 2 calls
Cypress._.times(2, () => cy.wait('@login_api'))
```

[image]

Comment: Appreciate the example! That explains the behavior of the second intercept I have. However, in my case, the two API calls are triggered separately. One is part of the login process, which is my setup in `beforeEach`. The other API call is inside the test. I can't see if there's a way for me to use one wait on both intercepts. Is there a way I can make them intercept by order? As in, the first intercept takes the first API response, and the second intercept takes the second?

Comment: Just make sure to move the intercept to before the first trigger, it will be all good.

Comment: Where you apply the waits depends on the test sequence. You can do them both together as I have shown or do something in between (probably an action - a click() say - that triggers the 2nd request).

Comment: But from your recent edit, I see you are not understanding the solution. Do not use two intercepts for the same URL because the second will over-shadow the first.

Comment: Or if you do set up two intercepts, make sure you wait for the first one before setting up the second. But there's really no point in having two intercepts, it's ugly and confusing for anyone reading your code.

Comment: What if I need to stub the response for the second API call as well? I need to stub different responses for these two API calls. First time is for the login. Second time is within the test after a button click.

Comment: It's another question - but it's covered in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very versatile solution, but an easy solution is to try to specify timeout

```
cy.wait('@login_api', { timeout: 100000 })
```

Comment: Let me know if I'm doing anything wrong but if I were to add it in the `beforeEach`, it does not solve the original issue where the wait only starts after the API calls finish. So there is nothing to wait anymore no matter how long it waits. It just feels like the `wait()` is triggered too "slow"